# Regex removing multiple brackets

Tags: r, regex

Hi I have a string that looks like
`string = "Tom (Marketing Assistant)/Gary (Manager)/Forty"` and I want to remove all the parts inside the brackets such that the outcome is `"Tom/Gary/Forty"`.

I've tried `string %>% str_remove("\\(.+\\)")` but the output is `"Tom /Forty"` and it seems that because the regex matching takes the very first `(` and up till the very last `)` which I tried visualizing with `string %>% str_extract("\\(.+\\)")` which gives `"(Marketing Assistant)/Gary (Manager)"`. I can't specify too specific what is inside the bracket because there is a range of characters in the brackets (not all the same), so is there a way to code it in a way that only removes what is inside the brackets, possibly by telling it to stop removing once it encounters `/` because this follows every bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_remove_all` to remove all the occurrences.

```
stringr::str_remove_all(string, '\\(.*?\\)')
#[1] "Tom /Gary /Forty"
```

In base R, use `gsub` -

```
gsub('\\(.*?\\)', '', string)
```

This removes all the characters between opening and closing round brackets. Question mark (`?`) makes the regex non-greedy so it matches only till the first closing bracket. All such occurrences are removed since we are using `str_remove_all`/`gsub`.

Comment: Yes I realized using the greedy matching with ```*?``` would help achieve the task, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can also do

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(string, "[(][^)]+[)]", "")
#[1] "Tom /Gary /Forty"
```